# How to calculate two input values and put the result in another input field in Vue,js?

Tags: vue.js

Here are my input fields:

```
<input v-model="form.sale_quantity" @change="computed" type="number" class="form-control" name="sale_quantity" id="sale_quantity" placeholder="Quantity">

<input v-model="form.sale_rate" @change="computed" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="sale_rate" id="sale_rate" placeholder="Rate">

<input v-model="form.sale_total" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="sale_total" id="sale_total" placeholder="Total Price">
```

I am using on change method to check whether the two input fields have some values and then calculate them.

```
data() {
    return {                
        form: new Form({
            sale_quantity: '',
            sale_rate: '',
            sale_total: '',
        })
    }
},
methods: {              
    computed() {
        //computation here
    }
}
```

So what should be my computed() method to check the input fields and calculate them to fill in the third input field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you really want to keep your form object you'll need to write your own event handler instead of using `v-model`

https://jsfiddle.net/575dtfqz/1/

```
<input :value="form.sale_quantity" @change="updateQuantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="sale_quantity" id="sale_quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
<input :value="form.sale_rate"  @change="updateRate" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="sale_rate" id="sale_rate" placeholder="Rate">
<input v-model="form.sale_total" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="sale_total" id="sale_total" placeholder="Total Price">
```

javascript:

```
methods: {
    updateQuantity(event) {
        this.form.sale_quantity = event.target.value
        this.form.sale_total = this.form.sale_quantity * this.form.sale_rate
    },
    updateRate(event) {
        this.form.sale_rate = event.target.value
        this.form.sale_total = this.form.sale_quantity * this.form.sale_rate
    }
}
```

Comment: I have other form data and need to send them to my controller. :value is taking my input as an event and the output is NaN and the input data is vanishing after clicking in other input field

sale_quantity:Event
sale_rate:Event
sale_total:NaN

Comment: I have updated my code and this is working now. Thanks @crystalwill

Answer (score 5):

Although there already is an accepted answer and it works this is the perfect use case for computed property and it should be used instead of methods.

Below is the working example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#el",
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        sale_quantity: 0,
        sale_rate: 0,
        sale_total: 0
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    total: function() {
      let calculatedTotal = this.form.sale_quantity * this.form.sale_rate;
      this.sale_total = calculatedTotal;
      
      return calculatedTotal;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <input v-model="form.sale_quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="sale_quantity" id="sale_quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
  <input v-model="form.sale_rate" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="sale_rate" id="sale_rate" placeholder="Rate">
  <input :value="total" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="sale_total" id="sale_total" placeholder="Total Price">
  <br>
  Total: {{sale_total}}
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is the best one. But there is an issue. How my sale_total of the form will receive the value of 'total' ?

Comment: thanks so much. Check my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885417/how-can-i-add-a-v-model-value-to-a-form-and-submit-it-as-the-form-data Can I solve that in the way you answered this one?

Comment: And yeah sale_total is getting the value in this way..console.log is showing me the value but in the form object in vue in the inspection section , sale_total value is null,

Answer (score 3):

I needed to operate several rows and had problems with the index of each control, this example helped me a lot to solve this problem

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
<table>
<thead align="left">
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Subtotal</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <td><input v-model.number="item.qty" size="10"></td>
      <td><input v-model.number="item.price" size="10"></td>
      <td><input v-model.number="subtotalRow[index]" readonly size="10"></td>
      <td><button @click="addRow(index)">+</button></td>
      <td><button @click="removeRow(index)">-</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
     <td>{{total}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

**JavaScript (vue.js)**

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
  data: {
    // dummy data
    items: [
    {qty: 5, price: 25 },
    {qty: 2, price: 16 },
    {qty: 8, price: 320 },
    {qty: 3, price: 88 }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    subtotalRow() {
      return this.items.map((item) => {
        return Number(item.qty * item.price)
      });
    },
    total() {
      return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + item.qty * item.price;
      }, 0);
    }
},
methods: {
    addRow(index) {
        this.items.splice(index + 1, 0, {
        qty: 1,  price: 0
        });
    },
    removeRow(index) {
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }  
});
```

See the example in https://jsfiddle.net/h5swdfv5/1/

Answer by **smarx** https://stackoverflow.com/a/45425666/4191716

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do the same thing, trying a little bit in my case it worked for me :)

```
<input v-model="form.sale_quantity">

<input v-model="form.sale_rate" >

<input :value="form.sale_quantity*form.sale_rate" placeholder="Total Price">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/575dtfqz/64/